# Unsuccessful: alter table add constraint: Table doesn't exist on create

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have strange behavior with OneToMany:

Entity1:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "entity1")
private Set<Deal> deals;
```

Deal:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "entity1_id")
private Entity1 entity1;
```

Also I have:

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
```

It gives following error upon start:

```
ERROR: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table deal add constraint FK_d17qqf8ra0ibdsnngbp465qvs foreign key (entity1_id) references entity1 (entity1_id)
ERROR: org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport - Table 'test.deal' doesn't exist
```

I tried drop all tables from db, all tables are created successfully (I have this type of relationship in other entities, those tables are also created) except of this one. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `Deal` (and `Entity1`) class is annoted with `@Entity`?

Comment: already tables with same name exist? then try dropping them and run the program, or instead of `create` try using `create-drop`..

Comment: @redflar3 As wrote in my question, I tried to drop all tables. Create-drop doesn't make any difference.

Comment: can you try changing this to `@JoinColumn(name = "entity1_id2")`

Comment: @redflar3 I tried, it didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found what the problem was.
To name my fields I used MySQL key words: to, from, show. 
So the SQL create request generated by Hibernate was complete gibberish for MySQL, and the only sign was the message from the server that the syntax was wrong.
I found it by deleting fields each after other and restarting, step by step.

Comment: I got a `from` field. Thanks for your hint!